# Is it ideal for SE to prematurely close area51 proposals attracting new users?

Tags: discussion, area-51, definition-phase

Stack Exchange is based on having a big and increasing community of people who are interested in new things, in asking new questions and in answering new questions.

Sometimes a new community out there will start a big effort to recruit followers for an area51 definition phase. But they can be close for many reasons, even though they might be doing well in terms of follower recruitment and question upvoting.

As an example: Recently, SE closed a [Neuroscience proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284151/who-really-has-the-expertise-regarding-how-new-area-51-communities-should-organi)  when it was 6 questions away from reaching commitment phase. This proposal had attracted a large proportion of followers new to stack exchange. Some of these people were leading experts interested in establishing a community in SE's backyard.

Does it make sense for SE to close the site before it can really evaluate how many people are there committed this new site, what is their level of expertise outside SE, what kind of take they will have on the subject.

What I'm arguing is that: even if the proposal is a partial duplicate of another area51 site, it is not convenient for SE to kill the proposal before the new users (new experts) establish themselves as frequent users of SE.

In this recent example, the users of Neuroscience were referred to another site, but most of them stopped their SE momentum.

Comment: Highly related: [Who really has the expertise regarding how new Area 51 communities should organize?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284151/who-really-has-the-expertise-regarding-how-new-area-51-communities-should-organi)

Comment: Yes. But different question. Not about expertise but about user retention.

Comment: Also, the 'What if?' idea was shut down, when it had reached over 200 committers in the commitment phase - however, a more focused proposal has emerged out of the ashes.

Comment: Typically proposed sites are only shut down when the are significantly overlapping another site or proposal, or when they take too long to advance to the next phase. You may have thought the site was 6 questions away from advancing, but a different perspective could say the proposal took a year to get to that point.

Comment: @psubsee2003 what exactly do you mean by "a different perspective could say the proposal took a year"? The proposal was started in June and by the end of July had 150 followers and was 6 questions away. What other perspective is there other than the actual data?

Comment: @glopes i was speaking in generalities. Since the specific proposal is deleted, we can't see the exact details anymore. A site, in general, could be 6 questions away, but if it took 12 months to advance that far, it probably isn't viable. If the proposal in question moved more quickly as you say, then it was likely delete for another reason. The most common one is the fact that it significantly overlapped with another site or proposal.

Comment: Then the question remains. Is it a good strategy to delete it before solidifying new expert users?